# Run cron script daily at 5pm EST

Tags: python, linux, cron

I'm trying to figure out how to set cron to run every day at 5 PM EST Is this correct?

`0 22 * * *`

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you can use this link (https://crontab.guru/)

Comment: Thanks!! I've used this link but it's not helpful in terms of displaying the timezone

Comment: cron uses the time of the machine on which it is run.

Answer (score 2):

```
0 22 * * *
```

Runs it at 22:00 every night. The timing specifically, depends on the timezone of your server

Answer (score 1):

I highly suggest using the https://crontab.guru/ website, which allows you to test crontab values with their results

To answer your question, yes that is valid, you can test your input with crontab guru ;)